# TS2322 type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

Knowing how to *call functions*, I'm completely puzzled by an error TS gives me:

```
src/external-db-connections.ts:20:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>)' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.

20     password: pgUri.password(), // WAT
       ~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/external-db-connections.ts:20
```

in this code:

```js
import * as URI from 'urijs';

const dbConnstringFactory =
  (singleVarName: string, more: TypeOrmModuleOptions) =>
  (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => {
  let connstring = configService.get<string>(singleVarName);
  let pgUri = new URI(connstring);
  return {
    type: 'postgres',
    database: pgUri.path().replace(/^[/]/, ''),
    host: pgUri.hostname(),
    port: Number(pgUri.port()),
    username: pgUri.username(),
    password: pgUri.password(), // WAT
    ...more
  }
}
```

where `urijs` is at [1.19.11](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs/v/1.19.11), and I've got `@types/urijs` at [1.19.25](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/urijs/v/1.19.25); both latest.

The `.d.ts` typings [declare](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2a00dd1bfb0153399653598a2bc74969929c13da/types/urijs/index.d.ts#L258) `URI.password` method as returning strictly `string`, when called with no arguments. Which I do.

Typings do match [urijs apidoc](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-password).

What am I missing, what's going wrong here? Is it TypeScript compiler bug?.. `tsc` version 4.9.5 from npm.

---

**Edits:** fairly **minimal repro** — in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ulidtko/408b45c4e7b126fb7c28c69140604546).

And just for good measure: no, I'm not assigning a wider type to a narrower one. Opposite:

```js
    // LHS has type  string | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>);

    password: pgUri.password(),

    // RHS has type  string
```

So why can't I set a property of type `string | ....` to a value of type `string`?

Comment: _"why can't I set a property of type `string | ....` to a value of type `string`?"_ - because it might be `....`, which is **not** `string`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I'm **assigning** the property. To a value of type `string`.

Comment: The error tells you the right-hand side is wider than the left-hand side; assignment the other way [would be fine](https://tsplay.dev/mLO42N). Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's exactly the opposite: I'm assigning a `string` value to a property of type `string | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>)`. TS messes up contravariance in the double arrow function. I'll try to minimize.

Comment: You are probably assigning the `dbConnstringFactory` to something that reads `password` as string. Take a look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLYCGBnPAdzgCcATALij2BIEsA7AcygB8oAKDgSmQD5qtRk17suvJAIAKJOAFs6eCAB4a9Zn27oAvunQAzAK4MAxsDpwGUAEaG6AGzLw4PKFWdpMWEhGCGSVhhYwbgExORUAOT6CJFeULq66Pa+UPpUasLINnaOzjwAdKFEpGQA3EA). Could be your issue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks, this is close. I'm passing the result of `dbConnstringFactory` to a function parameter, something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLYCGBnPAdzgCcATALij2BIEsA7AcygB8oAKDgSmQD5qtRk17suvJAIAKJOAFs6eCAB4a9Zn27oAvunQAzAK4MAxsDpwGUAEaG6AGzLw4PKFWdpMWEhGCGSVhhYwbgExORUAOT6CJFeULq66AD0yfa+UPpUasLINnaOzjwAdKFEpGQA3HqgkFAAQjgkeUFYcgDWzlQcxb1NTHhUOAwgANoAuhICzjp66cA2TVSNzSitUB1d+Q5OCDpAA)

Comment: @all minimized repro added, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

This dummy annotation resolves the error for me:

```js
const dbConnstringFactory =
  (singleVarName: string, more: TypeOrmModuleOptions) =>
  (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => {
  let connstring = configService.get<string>(singleVarName);
  let pgUri = new URI(connstring);
  return {
    type: 'postgres',
    database: pgUri.path().replace(/^[/]/, ''),
    host: pgUri.hostname(),
    port: Number(pgUri.port()),
    username: pgUri.username(),
    password: pgUri.password(),
    ...more
  } as TypeOrmModuleOptions
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- fix
}
```

Therefore, I'm pretty sure it's a **bug in TypeScript inference**.

Because there's another annotation (on line 3) specifying the return type as `TypeOrmModuleOptions`.

Somehow, with the 2nd annotation the misleading error-message on the password line is not emitted at all.

Comment: You could try to simplify this further and then report an issue.